# Displaying Chart with data retrieved from Entity Framework in Controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, chart.js

I have a database with news articles. I'm trying to make a chart with dates on the x-axis and stock price on the y-axis but something must be wrong with the datapoints because it's only showing a blank canvas with the title/subtitle.

ArticleModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace SPScraper
{
    [Table("Article")]
    public class Article 
    {
        private string id;
        private string header;
        private string image;
        private string url;
        private string author;
        private string date;
        private string content;
        private decimal? stockPriceOpen;
        private decimal? stockPriceClose;

        public virtual string Id {
            get { return id; }
            set { id = value; }
        }
        public virtual string Header {
            get { return header; }
            set { header = value; }
        }
        public virtual string Image {
            get { return image; }
            set { image = value; }
        }
        public virtual string Url {
            get { return url; }
            set { url = value; }
        }


        public virtual string Author {
            get { return author; }
            set { author = value; }
        }
        public virtual string Date
        {
            get { return date;  }
            set { date = value; }
        }
        public virtual string Content
        {
            get { return content; }
            set { content = value; }
        }

        public virtual decimal? StockPriceOpen {
            get { return stockPriceOpen; }
            set { stockPriceOpen = value;  }
        }

        public virtual decimal? StockPriceClose
        {
            get { return stockPriceClose; }
            set { stockPriceClose = value; }
        }

    }
}
```

ArticlesController.cs

```
 public ActionResult Timeline()
    {
        var articleQuery = from a in artDb.dbArticle
                           select new { a.Date, a.StockPriceClose };

        List<DataPoint> dataPoints = new List<DataPoint>();


        foreach (var item in articleQuery)
        {
            double stockPriceClose = double.Parse(item.StockPriceClose.ToString());
            DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Date);

            new DataPoint(date, stockPriceClose);
        }             

        ViewBag.DataPoints = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataPoints);
        return View();
    }
    JsonSerializerSettings _jsonSetting = new JsonSerializerSettings() { NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore };
```

DataPointModel.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Runtime.Serialization;

namespace SPScraperWeb.Models
{
    [DataContract]
    public class DataPoint
    {
        public DataPoint(DateTime x, double y)
        {
            this.X = x;
            this.Y = y;
        }

        //Explicitly setting the name to be used while serializing to JSON.
        [DataMember(Name = "x")]
        public Nullable<DateTime> X = null;

        //Explicitly setting the name to be used while serializing to JSON.
        [DataMember(Name = "y")]
        public Nullable<double> Y = null;
    }
}
```

Timeline.cshtml

```
    @model IEnumerable<SPScraper.Article>

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Timeline";
}
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://canvasjs.com/assets/script/canvasjs.min.js"></script>

<h2>@Html.ActionLink("Articles", "Index") | @Html.ActionLink("Timeline", "Timeline")</h2>

<div id="chartContainer">

    <script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload =  $(function(result) {
            var chart = new CanvasJS.Chart("chartContainer", {
                theme: "light2",
                zoomEnabled: true,
                animationEnabled: true,
                title: {
                    text: "Facebook Stock Price by Article"
                },
                subtitles: [
                {
                    text: "Try Zooming and Panning"
                }
                ],
                data: [
                {
                    type: "line", 
                    dataPoints: @Html.Raw(ViewBag.DataPoints),
                }]
            });
            chart.render();
        });
    </script>
</div>
```

[Blank Canvas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VKBnz.png)

Comment: Script tag inside a div is an odd place to put it.

Comment: You probably have to `JSON.parse()` what is in your `ViewBag` so that it is not just a string but I don't have experience with CanvasJS specifically.

Comment: @Crowcoder   Without the script tag, the function will show as text on the website. As for the CanvasJS, the datapoints expect a { x: value, y: value } format.

Comment: I'm not saying remove the script tag, I'm saying it is very unconventional to nest it within a `div`. And your canvas library probably requires a javascript object, not a string, so try `JSON.parse`'ing it.

Comment: Isn't this parsing the object? `ViewBag.DataPoints = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataPoints);`

Comment: I just noticed that while articleQuery in the ArticlesController is returning the data as _{ Date = "2018-03-28", StockPriceClose = 153.03 }_ the datapoints count is 0. Any idea what's wrong?

Comment: No, that is server side, you have to create a javascript object on the client too. I just looked at the docs for CanvasJS. It is looking for a javascript array, it doesn't look like it will parse a string to an object for you.

Comment: Try this, maybe you will understand what I'm saying. Instead of using the ViewBag data, hard-code an array of data points in your javascript just for testing so you can see it work.

Comment: u never added it to the collection

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**u never added it to the collection**

see below

```
public ActionResult Timeline()
{
    var articleQuery = from a in artDb.dbArticle
                       select new { a.Date, a.StockPriceClose };

    List<DataPoint> dataPoints = new List<DataPoint>();


    foreach (var item in articleQuery)
    {
        double stockPriceClose = double.Parse(item.StockPriceClose.ToString());
        DateTime date = Convert.ToDateTime(item.Date);

        **
        var dataPoint =  new DataPoint(date, stockPriceClose);
        dataPoints.add(dataPoint )
        **
    }             

    ViewBag.DataPoints = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataPoints);
    return View();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is using the viewbag object as json object, but it is actually a string,
[JsonConvert.SerializeObject](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/M_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonConvert_SerializeObject.htm) return type is a string you can check the documentation and see Return Value Type: **A JSON string representation of the object.**

```
    ViewBag.DataPoints = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(dataPoints);
```

this will be string, you need to parse that string to JSON object, 
you can use [JSON.parse()](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_parse.asp) function to do this.

```
 dataPoints: JSON.parse('@Html.Raw(ViewBag.DataPoints)')
```

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any data in ViewBag.DataPoints but the query is returning them correctly. Is the issue from the DataPointModel?